# Why do I get special characters when reading a file in binary mode?

Tags: python, file, binary, hex

[HxD]
-> 30 82 01 22 30

[Python]

```
with open("{filename}", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(5)
    print(byte)
```

-> b'0\x82\x01"0'

I expect b'\x30\x82\x01\x22\x30'
how can I print like this?

Maybe I think \x22 -> ASCII 34 -> "
how can I fix this?

Comment: b'0\x82\x01"0' == b'\x30\x82\x01\x22\x30' is True

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to fix. `b'\x30\x82\x01\x22\x30' == b'0\x82\x01"0'`. That is the same bytestring, just like `1.000 == 1.0` - different literal, same value. There is only one canonical representation though, since Python can't know which of the equivalent representations you might desire. When you print the result of `1.2 - 0.2` you get `1.0`, not `1.000`, and you need to convert it to a string by formatting to get it to look like `1.000` if that is what you want your output to look like. It is the same mechanism at work here.

(Also, `0` and `"` are not special characters. `\x82` and `\x01` are special characters here, as they do not exist inside ASCII, which is why they are escaped in the canonical representation.)

Now, if you just want to print `b'\x30\x82\x01\x22\x30'` because you believe it would be prettier for your end user, you will have to construct that string yourself; for example,

```
bs = b'0\x82\x01"0'
bs_alt_repr = "b'" + "".join(fr"\x{c:02x}" for c in bs) + "'"
print(bs_alt_repr)
# => b'\x30\x82\x01\x22\x30'
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file in binary mode, special characters can appear because binary mode treats the file content as a sequence of raw bytes, without any interpretation or encoding. Binary mode allows you to read the actual binary data stored in the file, including control characters, special characters, and non-printable characters.

you make modify the code by adding the repr which shows actual value of the byte instead of the escape sequence

```
with open("signCert.der", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(5)
    print(repr(byte))
```

Comment: `print(byte)` and `print(repr(byte))` give the exact same output.